# how can i get array from child and save in struct from firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fast question that i not found exactly here.

I have a struct that save all data from my firebase user.
The problem is that my user have an dynamic list, always can be 0, or have 3 or more lines of type [String:Int], in resume i think a_trips is [[String:Int]]

my actual struct:

```
struct User {

let fullname: String
let location: String
let uid: String

let a_trips: ? 

    
init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    
    self.uid = uid
    self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
    self.location = dictionary["location"] as? String ?? ""
    
    // i dont know to get array of array of a_trips here
    

    
}
```

}

example of user in firebase:

```
id:{

   uid:{
      
      fullname: "name",
      uid: "121948349238",
      location: "example location",
      a_trips: {
         "trip1": {
            id: 1432542543 (int)
         },
         "trip2": {
            id: 1523524654 (int)
         }
         ...
      }

   }

}
```

or... sometimes can be:

```
id:{

   uid:{
      
      fullname: "name",
      uid: "121948349238",
      location: "example location",
      a_trips: {
        // nil
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for your answer. The only thing I can't do is retrieve the list of a_trips from the database and assign it to a variable of the type [[int:int]] (example of 0: 111, 1:111 etc..), to save it in the user struct and refer to it later. I don't know if I am explaining myself correctly. Thank you!

Comment: How can i do that with map? In code. TripsArray is simple [Int:Int] sorry. Thats is [[int:int]] finally

Comment: I know, thats why i like to remove TripsArray. I just edit first question for simplify . thanks for all Joakim

Comment: So now it is a dictionary of string/int, `let a_trips: [String: Int]?`

Comment: let a_trips: [String: Int]?,  and then,   self.a_trips = dictionary["a_trips"] as? [String: Int]
        print(a_trips) . but the result still nil

Comment: Then I can’t help you anymore, maybe someone who knows firebase can help you.

Comment: Thanks for all Joakim. Can you push de Request +1 Please? Thanks!!

Comment: Should be [String: [String:Int]] not [String: Int]

Comment: Firebase is a collection of different solutions; for the database there's the Realtime Database (RTDB) and then Firestore. They are *very* different and the solution to your question will be different depending on which one you use. Please tag the question correctly. You can remove the `struct` and `performance` tags as they are not applicable. When done, comment back and notify me with and at symbol with my name, like @Jay

Comment: Thank you @jay for the answer. I run on RTDB

Comment: Just so you know this `a_trips: { // nil }` is not possible in the Realtime Databaes. A parent node cannot exist without a child. As soon as the child is removed and there are no child nodes lift, the parent is removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thanks so much all. I could find the solution

```
struct User {

 let fullname: String
 let location: String
 let uid: String

 
 // i finally create a simple array
 var tripList: [Int]

    
 init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    
    self.uid = uid
    self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
    self.location = dictionary["location"] as? String ?? ""
    
    var arrayTripsAux = [Int]()
    if let a_trips = dictionary["a_trips"] as? [String: [String:Int]]{
        
        for t in a_trips.values{
            arrayTripsAux.append(t["id"] ?? 0)
        }
        
    } else {
        arrayTripsAux.append(0)
    }
    
    // return childs in array
    self.tripList = arrayTripsAux
    

    
 }
```